# Django with Gunicorn Serves Only One Request at a Time

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

I have deployed my Django project to Google Cloud.
It has a RAM of 1.7GB and 1 shared core, running on Ubuntu 20.0.4.
I have used Nginx as reverse proxy and to serve static files and Gunicorn behind it to serve as WSGI handler.

I have run some performance tests using Apache Bench.
Now it seems that Gunicorn is serving only one request at a time.
I had turned off Nginx and run Gunicorn in port 80 to see if Nginx was the bottleneck, and it wasn't.

I have checked with python manage.py server and it serves 7.26 requests per second with nearly 138ms response time.
The problem is when I run it with Gunicorn it shows almost the same result or sometimes even worse.

I am developing an e-commerce website which performs database I/O.
I have used gevent as worker class.
I have run the following command-
/var/www/grocery-app/g_env/bin/gunicorn grocery.wsgi --workers 3 --worker-class gevent --worker-connections 100 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000

Nginx reads the server from local port 8000.

I have run the test from Apache Bench with 100 requests in 100 connections, 50 requests in 50 connections, 50 request in 10 connections.
No matter what combination I choose the result always seems to be the same.

I have run with --log-level debug to see what's happening.
It seems that it takes all the requests together (shows GET / ) but responds much much later.

My PostgreSQL settings-
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 1536MB
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 2621kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB

which I have generated from https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua.

I am using Django 2.2.4, PostgreSQL 12, Gunicorn 20.1.0.

Comment: I have a suspicion that `--worker-class gevent` doesn't play nicely with Django... At least not how you think it will. Also, 3 workers is not much for an application that takes nearly half a second to generate a response. You can try using asgi, but that won't help much if your views aren't asynchronous.

Comment: My views are synchronous. Any feasible solution to this?

Comment: I was using html-minify package which now seems to take some time. Removed it and response time is now close to 138ms i.e. 7.26 request per second with manage.py runserver.

Comment: I can't test it nor cannot find any confirmation of my theory, but I think that `--worker-class gevent` in this example can only help with collecting the request from the client and serving the response (in some cases), but it probably doesn't help with processing it. That being said, as you have only 3 workers, your application can only process 3 requests at once in the best scenario. In the worst one, when `gevent` is changing how workers are spawned, it may be always limited to one. I suggest changing those 2 settings to observe the difference.

Comment: In my case the 3 workers are actually serving one request at a time. If they served 3 requests at once the responses should have been more than 21 requests per second, but I'm getting the same output as manage.py runserver.

Comment: hi @HqShiblu, I'm having similar issues with my setup. Apache + gunicorn + uvicorn. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I've switched to Linode server with dedicated CPU cores and it performs well. Gunicorn cannot take the full advantage of worker classes with shared cores, or at least in my case.